# How to insert data into table cells without defining column name in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to create html table dynamically as per `mysql` table data. 
First of all I print all the db column names as `th` in html by separating the keys from the result array. Now the result array look like below

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 25
        [1] => http://google.com
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 26
        [1] => http://hotmail.com
    )

 )
```

I want array in this way because I don't know how many columns each db table has. So I want to print them dynamically in `<td>`'s.

```
foreach($result_array as $key => $val){

    echo "<tr id=".$val[0].">";
    echo "<td>".$val[1]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

I want to increment one in every next step of `$val[0]`. Not Like loops they do one step for all in one round, as I mention in above `foreach $val[0] $val[1]` I want `0 and 1` dynamically in one round not typed by hand.

I want just like this

```
 foreach($result_array as $key => $val){

    echo "<tr id=".$val[$key].">";  // $key = 0
    echo "<td>".$val[$key]."</td>"; // $key = 1
    echo "</tr>";

 }
```

Comment: What is the question? I must admit I don't know what you are asking. Is something not working or ar you getting an error?

Comment: ok let met add more into my question

Comment: There is still too much detail missing. How do you generate `$values` for a start

Comment: I just edited my question, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "YOUR USERNAME";
$password = "YOUR PASSWORD"; //if set password you mysql 
$dbname = "YOURDATABASE";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);} 
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($row[0]);
        //echo "id: " . $row[0]. " - Name: " . $row[1]. " " . $row[2]. "<br>"; ?>  
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>     
  <?php   } ?>
```